any contingent labor and capital demand functions shortcuts for cobb-douglas functions?
for cobb-douglas utility functions,
aI/px and (a-1)I/py gives the marshallian demand for x and y.
Are there any parallels for cobb-douglas production functions,
q = x^a * y^(1-a) ?
Thank you.

Are you doing cost minimization or profit maximization?

I wasn't looking for a specific one, just wondering if there's a shortcut for either cost minimization or profit maximization.

Yes, there are, but demand does not exist independently of the objective.

Let $q= f(x,y)$ be the prodution function. the equivalence of utility maximization for production is the output maximisation problem:
$$
q(p_x, p_y, c) = \max f(x,y) \text{ s.t. } p_x x + p_y y = c.
$$
This maximizes the output given the total expenditure on inputs. The function $q(p_x, p_y, c)$ is similar to the indirect utility function.
Given the solutions $x = a c/p_x$ and $y = (1-a) c/p_y$ we easily arrive at the expression:
$$
q(p_x, p_y, c) = c \left(\left(\frac{a}{p_x}\right)^a \left(\frac{1-a}{p_y}\right)^{1-a}\right).
$$
Now, the cost minimization problem is given by:
$$
c(p_x, p_y, q) = \min p_x x + p_y y \text{ s.t. } f(x,y) \ge q.
$$
The function $c(p_x, p_y, q)$ gives the minimal expenditure necessary to produce an output level of $o$. It is similar to the expenditure minimization problem.
It is known that inverting $q(p_x, p_y, c)$ with respect to $c$ gives the function $c(p_x, p_y, q)$. So in this case, we immediately get that:
$$
c(p_x, p_y, q) = q\left(\left(\frac{p_x}{a}\right)^{a}\left(\frac{p_y}{(1-a)}\right)^{1 - a}\right).
$$
This shows that marginal costs are constant and equal to $\left(\left(\frac{p_x}{a}\right)^{a}\left(\frac{p_y}{(1-a)}\right)^{1 - a}\right)$
Here, trying to get an expression for the profit function does not make much sense. As the Cobb-Douglass production function is CRS, profits (under price taking) are either zero or unbounded.

"Here profit maximization does not make sense." This seems strangely phrased, since many GE models assume CRS + profit maximization. (You yourself mention zero profit as a possible solution.) Or are you arguing that GE models do not make sense?

@Giskard I mean that it does not make sense to try to have an expression for the profit function (as a function of output and input prices).

I see and like your rephrasing.
